# GStreamer SDK installation on Mac

Tags: macos, gstreamer

Can someone please let me know the proper steps for installing **Gstreamer SDK** on Mac. I followed the steps on the following
 website:http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+on+Mac+OS+X

After installing the Runtime and development files I cannot find: **Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Current/share/gst-sdk/tutorials**. Cannot see the Current folder.

New to **GStreamer** as well as Mac.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, gstreamer.com ist not part of the official GStreamer project. The project's URL is http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/.

The SDK available on gstreamer.com is based upon the GStreamer 0.10.x release. These versions have not been maintained by the GStreamer project for a couple of years already. The current stable version is 1.4.x.

I strongly suggest getting the SDK from the official GStreamer project page and start reading the documentation found there.

Returning to your original question. Apple decided to hide your personal Library folder. You can reach it as described in this KB:

https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18928

> The Library folder is hidden. If you need to open it for some reason,
>   click the desktop to make sure you’re in the Finder, hold down the
>   Option key, then choose Go > Library.